# Why is Tumbe hoovu favorite of lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

"Tumbe hoovu" also called as "Dronapushpi" has a scientific name 'Leucas cephalotes' is known as favorite flower of lord Shiva. Why is that so? Is there any specific reason for this?
[image: The image of the flower tumbe hoovu]

Comment: Because it is medicinal. With Love!